# How to convert JSON into Hashmap object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to automate PUT request for our rest service in which I am passing a PUT body. I am trying to use HashMap to create an object for the body and add the values to it.
I am not sure how to add values using Hashmap for the nested JSON elements.

My body is something like this:
{

```
    "versions": [
        {
            "versionname": "Test",
            "number": 1

        }
    ],
    "id": 19,
    "name": "TEST",


}
```

My code is as below:

```
public static Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("id", "2");
map.put("name", "TEST");
```

My question is how to add values for 'versionname' and 'number' element into the map so that I can pass that in my PUT request's body?   Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I feel like there's some important information that's missing here.  Are you using any libraries that is doing some of this work for you?  Your question title says json into hashmap, but the description of your question suggests you want to take a hashmap and turn it back into json?

Comment: `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, String>` and put a list of maps under the key *versions*

Comment: Sorry about the confustion. I want to take my JSON body, as shared above and put it in a Hashmap object and use that object as body to for my PUT request.

Comment: You can't put a `List` into a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Hi giorgiga,Can you please elaborate that for my example ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strict typing, do not use maps if you know your payload (typed from the top of my head, may not immediately compile):

```
public class Request {

  public static class Version {
    public String versionname;
    public int number;

    protected Version() {} // for deserializer

    public Version(String versionname, int number) {
      this.versionname = versionname;
      this.number = number;
    }
  }

  public List<Version> versions = new ArrayList<>();
  public int id;
  public String name;
}

Request request = new Request();
request.versions.add(new Version("Test", 1));
request.id = 19;
request.name = "TEST";

String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request);

Request deserialized = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Request.class);
```

Comment: thanks for the respone but we are trying to get away from creating separate class for the body object and trying to use Hashmap <String, Object> or Json object to create our body object. Do you have any insight on this ?

Comment: No. Unless you have something so generic that you cannot express it in any sensible structure, even a polymorphic one, I would not do it. It increases complexity, makes code less comprehensible, non-typesafe and error prone. Ultimately it costs more time in maintenance.